# What is $f(x, y) = |x| - |y|$ called?

Tags: geometry, 3d

$f(x,y)=x^2-y^2$ is your friendly neighbourhood hyperbolic paraboloid. $f(x, y) = |x| - |y|$ naturally has similar appearance. Do shapes of the latter form have a name?

Comment: Looks like a non-smooth saddle. [Wolfram Alpha plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot\[Abs\[x\]+-+Abs\[y\]\])

Comment: You could call $z=|x|+|y|$ a "circular cone" with *circle* here defined under the [1-norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space) $\|\cdot\|_1$ instead of the usual 2-norm $\|\cdot\|_2$, but I can't think of anything standard for $z=|x|-|y|$. I submit the term "four-plane saddle" for any shape given by $$z=ax+b|x|+cy+d|y|,$$ or any invertible affine transformation thereof, with $$\mathrm{sgn}(a+b)=\mathrm{sgn}(-a+b)=\pm1,$$ $$\mathrm{sgn}(c+d)=\mathrm{sgn}(-c+d)=\mp1.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about *hyperbolic superparaboloid* analogous to quadric - [superquadric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superquadric)?

Comment: I'll go with it. Mine's just $f(x, y) = |x|^m - |y|^n$ for $m = n = 1$.